# How should you set a dependent property that's related to a many-to-one field in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I made this basic example to illustrate what I'm talking about. Basically I want to automatically set the "HasEngine" property whenever an Engine is added to a Car. I believe the way to do this is to override the setter for either the Engine or the EngineId property of the Car class, but which one should it actually be done in? Or is there a better way to manage this kind of 'dependent' property?

```
public class Car
{
    public bool HasEngine { get; private set; }

    public int? EngineId { get; set; }
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}

public class Engine
{
    public int EngineId { get; set; }

    public IList<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

As far as EF Core goes I do want to store the HasEngine property in the database, I just don't want to have to set it manually every time

Comment: Maybe something like this? `public bool HasEngine => EngineId.HasValue;` And why store this value to db?

Comment: But in this case it's not getting stored in the database, right? The example I have is also a simplified version of the actual use case--in reality I have several properties that can set the dependent property. I could still technically do what you suggested on the getter with an if statement (or just make it a method). As for why I want to store it in the db, it's for reporting purposes (both in and outside the app)

Comment: OK, then you'll have to modify the setter for Car#Engine. But I still recommend you to try to solve your requirements in e.g. reports without this extra db column. It is quite easy to write SQL that mimics the behaviour you want. Doing what you're trying to do, is usually one of the first nails in the coffin for the app. BR

Comment: True. I guess another reason I thought this would be better is because the properties will only be set once in most cases, so logically it feels like it makes sense to set HasEngine when one of the (let's say) 5 properties is set instead of evaluating up to 5 properties every time HasEngine is accessed. Does that not really matter?

Comment: Good design should be the most important thing. When running into performance issues, then optimize. BR

Comment: I don' t see why anybody needs to store HasEngine in DB . Just enough [NotMapped]  public bool HasEngine { get { return EngineId!=null } }

Answer (score 0):

If you need the calculated value in reporting that's being done without the EF model, you can make HasEngine a calculated property in the database and a read-only property in EF.